# How to insert a sign in every two bit in dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, insert

I would like to modify the raw data in `df1` to the form of `df2`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['ABCDE'], ['RTY12'], ['SDWERTESR'],['R']], columns=[1])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['AB-CD-E'], ['RT-Y1-2'], ['SD-WE-RT-ES-R'],['R']], columns=[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty but would do the job:

```
In []:
import itertools as it
df1[1].apply(lambda s: '-'.join(''.join(x) for x in it.zip_longest(*[iter(s)]*2, fillvalue='')))

Out[]:
0          AB-CD-E
1          RT-Y1-2
2    SD-WE-RT-ES-R
3                R
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to do the trick:

```
>>> df1[1].apply(lambda s: ''.join('%s-' % c if i % 2 == 0 else c for i, c in enumerate(s, 1)))

0          AB-CD-E
1          RT-Y1-2
2    SD-WE-RT-ES-R
3                R
Name: 1, dtype: object
```